# SQL Query efficiency (JOIN or Cartesian Product )

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008, processing-efficiency

Hello I am Confused with three scenarios which commonly every one use in almost every project.

I wanted to Know which one of these will be Efficient accordinng to  
- Less Time Complexity  
- Efficiency  
-  effectiveness

**TableA (userid ,username, email , phone)**

**TableB (username,TestField)**

.

**Case 1**

```
select email, TestField from TableA , TableB 
where TableA.username =  TableB.username  and 
TableB.username = 'ABC'
group by email, TestField
```

**Case 2**

```
select email, TestField from TableA 
inner join TableB on TableB.username =  'ABC'
```

**Case 3**

```
declare @uname nvarchar(20);
set @uname = 'ABC';
declare  @Email nvarchar(20);

select  @Email= email from TableA where username =   @uname; 

select  @Email as email , TestField from TableB 
where username = @uname
```

Comment: On SQL Server you have the "Display Estimated Execution Plan" feature. It will show you how long the query took and also gives you a lot of information concidering efficieny. Just as a blind guess: Case 2 should be most effective and quick. Case 2 just builds the JOIN for username 'ABC'.

Comment: if we Conceder that we want whole data that matches the Joing Condition then Which one will B more efficient ?

Comment: A and B will not even produce the same result, so what do you consider more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 2 will give you a different output anyway, as you are not joining TableA and TableB in any way so you get a Cartesian product.

Since all of a sudden `email` came up, you will need a join in case 1:

In Case 1 you can simply rewrite the query to

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.Email , B.TestField 
  FROM TableA A join TableB B on A.username = B.Username
 WHERE B.username = 'ABC'
```

Which is more readable and easier to maintain as you do not ave a superfluous GROUP BY clause.

In Case 3 you have userId in your `where` clause, which is not even *in* your tableB according to your post.

In general, for maintainability and readibility:

Use *explicit* joins

```
SELECT * FROM A JOIN B ON A.id = B.id
```

is preferable over

```
SELECT * FROM A, B WHERE A.id = B.id
```

And use DISTINCT when you want distinct values, instead of GROUP BY over all columns:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a, b, b FROM TABLE
```

is preferable over

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM TABLE GROUP BY a, b, c
```

Comment: Case 1 cannot be rewritten as you suggest, because the original request was for `email` from table A and `Testfield` from table B.

Comment: No actually it was not. It was for username. I see the edits now and It does impact my answer. In the _original_ there was no mention of any email and table A was not used at all :)

Answer (score 0):

Most database experts will tell you that cross products are evil and to be avoided. Your first example would work just fine. It is an implicit inner join.

Your second example is syntactically incorrect. I suspect you'd get an error from MSSQL Server Manager. What you probably meant was:

```
select a.email, b.TestField 
from TableA a inner join TableB b 
  on (b.username = a.username)
where b.username = 'ABC'
```

Your first example will **probably** be the more efficient, since MSSQL Server is smart enough to do the projection on `TableB.username` before doing the join. I'm not so certain that this would be the case in the above version of case 2.

To be sure you could do it like this:

```
select a.email, b.TestField 
from TableA a inner join 
  (select * from TableB where TableB.username = 'ABC') b 
on (b.username = a.username)
where b.username = 'ABC'
```

Hope that helps.